# How to use the spring-security filters without an application context?

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to use the spring-security web-filters without a spring application-context (or spring container) straight from java code.

Is this possible? Can I call the different spring live-cycle methods directly and if so is there a sample of how to do that (which different interfaces to care of and their ordering)?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to reuse the funtionality of spring security but without the overhead of the container. I'd not need the container otherwise and don't want to introduce this xml concept etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's possible but it doesn't worth it.

Spring is a complicated framework that isolates you for the burden of configuring a Java application. Why do you want to use Spring without Spring?

Regarding your question, the formerly Spring security, Acegi, claimed that can be used without Spring.

So you can try, but your main problem is going to be to load the entire application at server startup. You'll need to duplicate the functionality that contains the ContextLoaderListener.

Try to create your own listener instead of

```
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And then configure the main servlet for your application (because I presume that you don't want to use Spring MVC) and the Security Filter as **Simeon** said.

And good luck.

Alternatively, you can try Apache [SHIRO](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks, however I do not want to instantiate a spring-application context. So propably like you and @simeon said spring-security is not the right thing. I am searching more for a library than a framework posted a new question therefore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840986/any-library-for-authentication-in-a-java-web-app

Answer (score 5):

> I want to use the spring-security web-filters without a spring application-context

**You can't.**

Because when you define the filter chain proxy in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

The `DelegatingFilterProxy` actually expects to find your `contextConfigLocation` and valid config files in there:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

    <!-- This must be valid otherwise your .war deployment will fail -->
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-contexts/spring-contexts.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I know the delegating filter does (because it looks up the actual chain in the context) but can I instantiate and setup the "real filters" like ExceptionTranslationFilter etc in plain java? I mean spring always says how unintursive their container is and than....

Comment: you can declare the classes as filters in your `web.xml`, and you can instantiate the individual objects (in the end, you will have almost a full spring context). But how will you set the object references needed by the filters?

Comment: I want to insantiate and set up everything in good old java (actually yeti ml) code, chain them together using a custom filter chain - similar to FilterChainProxy - and than run that one from web.xml.

Comment: @chrisichris it might be possible, but there is no single answer to that question than. Because every filter has separate requirements and you'd have to setup every single one differently. If you really want to do this download the spring source and look what at what is injected before each filter is used. This however is probably not worth it.

Comment: @chrisichris Its probably better to do as jbbarquero suggested and try using either Acegi security or Apache SHIRO as using spring without contexts defeats its purpose.