# Any library for authentication in a java web-app?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

Hi I am look for a proven java security web-library which is a bit more low-level and therefore less intrusive than the well known frameworks spring-security and apache shiro.

Just something which has best-practive utility-apis for example to encode a remember-me cookie or for dighest authentication, accessing ldap. All the sutff which is so useful in the above frameworks but without needing to follow the frameworks filters and indriections an application-context or yet another ini file etc.

Comment: LOL, you say in your post that you **don't** want anything like Spring Security and Shiro and then accept an answer that proposes it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always use the `HttpServletRequest.login()` method or `j_security_check` and implement an auth manager beneath it for your particular server, that's pretty much the default & low level standard thing... Your only real other choice is, as you mentioned, security frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) project it does a lot more then the standard libraries, and makes it really easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use either of one, use container-managed security which both Tomcat and Jetty provide.